# vbscript: selectednamespaces for soap response not working with xpath

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, vbscript

There have been some great answers to previous questions regarding defining namespaces for soap messages, however I can't seem to get mine working. The soap message is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <CM-AcctAutoFill xmlns="http://oracle.com/CM-AcctAutoFill.xsd">
            <request>
                <acctId>0000123456</acctId>
            </request>
            <response>
                <returnCode>0</returnCode>
                <autoFill>
                    <acctId>0000123456</acctId>
                    <ldcId>IL</ldcId>
                    <customerName>USER, TEST</customerName>
                    <phone>(888)444-1234</phone>
                    <enrlDt>1990-07-15</enrlDt>
                    <stopDt/>
                    <routingNo>088000014</routingNo>
                    <bankAccountNo>1234034721234</bankAccountNo>
                </autoFill>
                <serviceAddress>
                    <address>18 TEST LN</address>
                </serviceAddress>
            </response>
        </CM-AcctAutoFill>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And when I try to use xpath to get the account number and other responses in autoFill, I get nothing.  If I manually modify the file to take out "soap:" and the xmlns attributes, it works fine.

Here is my code, thanks in advance for any help. Note: this has to be done in vbscript, it is not my preference. The software this script will be placed in only accepts vbscript. This is also my first post so I apologize if I made any errors in formatting.

```
Dim response
response = "c:\webSvcReponseMulti.xml"

Dim oXML
Set oXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

oXML.load(response)
oXML.async = False
oXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
oXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' " & _
                                    "xmlns:r='http://oracle.com/CM-AcctAutoFill.xsd'"

Dim path
path = "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/r:CM-AcctAutoFill/r:response/r:autoFill/r:acctId"

Set acct = oXML.selectNodes(path)

For Each objNode In acct
    MsgBox objNode.text
Next
```

Comment: I would definitely move the `oXML.async = False` before the `load()` call but I have tried your code, it finds the id and displays it in a message box.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the move you suggested.  Also, I believe the issue may be something on my local machine or that I was loading the incorrect sample xml file.  I was able to get it to work in a different location.